# ggplot, data space according to sampling time?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to space the dates according to the days between sampling. Between some sampling there is 5 days and some 4 days.
data looks like this (also need to add to the labels BBCH):

```
 structure(list(Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("06.05.2016 BBCH 50–51", "09.05.2016 BBCH 51–53", 
"13.05.2016 BBCH 55–59", "16.05.2016 BBCH 59–61", "20.05.2016 BBCH 61–64"
), class = "factor"), Mean1 = c(0.9133333, 0.4366667, 0.313333, 
0.176, 0.4, 0.1533333, 0.2066667, 0.29, 0.4633333, 0.4833333), 
    sd = c(2.704973, 1.639598, 0.8780997, 0.5158375, 1.1213943, 
    0.5203121, 0.5461531, 0.6587969, 0.823153, 0.9965101), n = c(300L, 
    300L, 300L, 250L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L), Mean2 = c(0.15617168, 
    0.09466226, 0.05069711, 0.03262443, 0.06474373, 0.03004023, 
    0.03153216, 0.03803566, 0.04752476, 0.05753354), SNH = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("OC", "OF"
    ), class = "factor"), Round = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Round 1", "Round 2", 
    "Round 3", "Round 4", "Round 5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

and my script:

```
Pan_16<-qplot(x= Time,
              y=  Mean1,
              group= SNH,              
              data =  Plant) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean1- Mean2,
                    ymax = Mean1 + Mean2),
                width=0.2, size=1)+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(), ylim=c(0,2))+
  geom_line(size=1,aes(linetype = SNH)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=function(x){sub("\\s", "\n", x)})+
  scale_color_manual("Field type", values=c("#gray20", "#gray46"))+
  labs(title = "", x = "", y = "")+
  annotate("text", x = 1 , y = 1.3, label = c("* * * "), color="black",  size=5 , fontface="bold")+
  annotate("text", x = 2 , y = 0.8, label = c(" * * ") , color="black",  size=5 , fontface="bold")+
  annotate("text", x = 3 , y = 0.8, label = c("* * * "), color="black",  size=5 , fontface="bold")+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 1, colour = "grey80"))+
  theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"))+
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour="white"))
```

Comment: Try `Plant$Time <- as.Date(Plant$Time, "%d.%m.%Y")` and then use `scale_x_date` instead of the current `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Plant)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Plant, 20))`.

Comment: now it gives me error : Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Answer (score 2):

Sisi, to get you going ... also check that your `Time` variable is a factor. Always check the data type, if you do not get expected results or errors.

The praise goes to @Rui who basically gave you the answer.

I stripped off the superfluous stuff from your plot to help you see the major building blocks. You can add these layers for your desired plot/end result.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("06.05.2016 BBCH 50–51", "09.05.2016 BBCH 51–53", 
"13.05.2016 BBCH 55–59", "16.05.2016 BBCH 59–61", "20.05.2016 BBCH 61–64"
), class = "factor"), Mean1 = c(0.9133333, 0.4366667, 0.313333, 
0.176, 0.4, 0.1533333, 0.2066667, 0.29, 0.4633333, 0.4833333), 
    sd = c(2.704973, 1.639598, 0.8780997, 0.5158375, 1.1213943, 
    0.5203121, 0.5461531, 0.6587969, 0.823153, 0.9965101), n = c(300L, 
    300L, 300L, 250L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L), Mean2 = c(0.15617168, 
    0.09466226, 0.05069711, 0.03262443, 0.06474373, 0.03004023, 
    0.03153216, 0.03803566, 0.04752476, 0.05753354), SNH = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("OC", "OF"
    ), class = "factor"), Round = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Round 1", "Round 2", 
    "Round 3", "Round 4", "Round 5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
# ---------- coerce Time to character
df <- df %>% mutate(Time = as.character(Time)) 
# ---------- now make a Date column
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Time, "%d.%m.%Y")

# with the given data frame plot and set time axis
qplot(x= Date, y=  Mean1, group= SNH, data =  df) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean1- Mean2,
                      ymax = Mean1 + Mean2),
                  width=0.2, size=1) + 
# ------------- set a date scale and "configure" to your liking
scale_x_date(  date_labels = "%d %b"        # show day and month
             , date_breaks = "2 days"       # have a major break every 2 days
             ,date_minor_breaks = "1 day"   # show minor breaks in between
)
```

[image: ggplot: use of scale_x_date() and defining breaks]

**Amendment to show-case setting of user-defined axis breaks**

Scales support the setting of breaks. This allows to provide a vector of values or inject a function returning the desired breaks.

Below we replace the (regular) and preconfigured break setting of `date_breaks` by supplying a `breaks` statement.

```
# ---------- coerce Time to character
df <- df %>% mutate(Time = as.character(Time)) 
# ---------- now make a Date column
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Time, "%d.%m.%Y")

# with the given data frame plot and set time axis
qplot(x= Date, y=  Mean1, group= SNH, data =  df) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean1- Mean2,
                      ymax = Mean1 + Mean2),
                  width=0.2, size=1) + 
    # ------------- set a date scale and "configure" to your liking
    scale_x_date(  breaks = unique(df$Date)     # setting user defined breaks
                   ,minor_breaks = "1 day"      # keep minor breaks evenly spaced
                   ,date_labels = "%d %b"       # show day and month
```

This yields:

[image: ggplot: setting user-defined break for scale_x_date()]

Comment: Thanks for the credits given. And I would have upvoted anyway, it's a good answer showing how to set the date labels and breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the flowers, Rui! I am happy that I could add something useful.

Comment: Thank you both, very much, works good. Quick question, how can i set the labels, so it only shows the given dates? Right now it only shows dates after 2 or 3 (how i set it), but i can't find a way how to show only dates that were in my dataset. Or maybe there is a way to change the labels, because i need to add to dates also the bbch level

Comment: You can control the breaks of a scale. Supply a vector (or a function producing the desired breaks [note: with this you can construct fancy axis labels, if you ever need to, e.g. adding x days from a key date]). We have your desired breaks already in the dataframe. Thus, make `breaks = ...` point to this vector. As there are double entries, use `unique() for trim down to what you need.